# SSRS: Varying functionality by environment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there a recommended way to vary SSRS report behavior by environment?  For example, I have a click action that goes to a URL that will be different in each environment.  I'd prefer a clean solution, rather than editing the report file before each deployment.  Something similar to .NET's web.config transforms would be excellent.

Answer (score 0):

We store URL fragments like that in a database parameters table and have a shared dataset that pulls the values and then combine them in the report to create the final URL.